# How to insert date mysql python telegrambot

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

I always failled to insert data to Mysql database from my telegram bot, and always run Exception. Only `tanggald` allways failed to insert. I thing format of date insert query is wrong. How to write correct format?

`tanggald` column detail : Data Type = DATE

This is piece of code:

```
def process_lanjut(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        qlanjut = message.text
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        user.qlanjut=qlanjut

        d = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        next_monday = next_weekday(d, 4) 
        user.next_monday = next_monday
        print(user.next_monday)

        with con.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO diagnosa(sex, tanggald) VALUES('" + user.sex + "','" +next_monday+ "')"
            cursor.execute(sql)

        con.commit()
        con.close()

        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'thanks')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_end)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message,'oops lanjut')
```

On command line output : 2018-04-20 (data that should be INSERT to tanggald)

Comment: Where is your error message?

Comment: I did not initialize specific error message. I only send 'oops lanjut' when there is an error . 'cause the tanggald, the query is not executed @Sean

Answer (score 1):

That's not the proper way to insert data into table. Although your way *may* work, it is not safe and it lacks data escaping (`'`, `"`, etc.):

> The SQL representation of many data types is often different from their Python string representation. The typical example is with single quotes in strings: in SQL single quotes are used as string literal delimiters, so the ones appearing inside the string itself must be escaped, whereas in Python single quotes can be left unescaped if the string is delimited by double quotes.
>
> Because of the difference, sometime subtle, between the data types representations, a naïve approach to query strings composition, such as using Python strings concatenation, is a recipe for terrible problems.
>
> If the variables containing the data to send to the database come from an untrusted source (such as a form published on a web site) an attacker could easily craft a malformed string, either gaining access to unauthorized data or performing destructive operations on the database. This form of attack is called SQL injection and is known to be one of the most widespread forms of attack to database servers. Before continuing, please print this page as a memo and hang it onto your desk.

So in your case the `INSERT` statement should look like this:

```
with con.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = 'INSERT INTO diagnosa (sex, tanggald) VALUES (%s, %s)'
    data = (user.sex, next_monday)
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

---

Further reading:

1. [MySQL docs and example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)
2. [Similar article for PostgreSQL](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) (contains a better explanation of potential problems)